# how to position an element centrally and another floating right on the same line

Tags: css, css-position

At the very bottom of a page, I have this markup:

```
<footer class="general">
    <span class="fr">&copy; Copyright 2013</span>
    <h3>Stuff written here</h3>
</footer>
```

Class "fr" makes the element to float right. What I actually want to achieve, is to have both the heading and the span on the same line but I want the span to be floating right and the heading to be centered with respect to the full width, not between the left edge and the span (which is my current case).

Specific CSS code:

```
.general
{
    margin: 5px 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.fr
{
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about adding some styles to the `h3`?

[This works](http://jsfiddle.net/2CYqc/1/) for me:

```
.general
{
    margin: 5px 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.general h3
{
    width:250px;
    margin: 5px auto;
}
.fr
{
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using this CSS:

```
.general {
    position:relative;
}
.fr {
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
}
.general h3 {
    text-align:center;
    margin:0;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/N533X/)**

By changing the `.fr` class from `float:right` to `position:absolute; right:0` you remove it from the flow of the document so that the h3 element can be centered without it being affected by the span.

Comment: I'd really love to avoid absolute positioning as I am using .fr/fl classses for most of my positioning and things might get messed up. Also from what I've read, that's generally bad practice and not really a fix. If I can't fix it otherwise I'll use it, though, thanks a lot.